# applescript : updating properties?

Tags: applescript

This is probably a very basic question;

I always see

```
  make new document with properties { x: "1", y: "2", z: 3" }
```

But how do I update these properties later?

```
 tell first document

 -- i am trying to set the volume name property 
 set volume name of document to "BLA"
 -- also tried:
 set properties of first document to {volume name:"BLA"}

 end tell
```

But that doesn't work at all, what is the official syntax? Can't find it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to target the appropriate document (or whatever has the property), but the properties are accessed the same way as any other [record](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDGEAH) property, for example

```
tell application "whatever"
    set x of document 1 to "5" -- document 1 is usually the front document
    tell document 1 to set x to "5"
end tell
```

Note that an application property may not be writable - check its scripting dictionary.